# What is meant by "death of the religious learned men"?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

[Narrated](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/38) Abdullah bin Amr:

> I heard the Prophet (ﷺ) saying, "Allah will not deprive you of knowledge after he has given it to you, but it will be taken away through the death of the religious learned men with their knowledge. Then there will remain ignorant people who, when consulted, will give verdicts according to their opinions whereby they will mislead others and go astray."

Does "death of the religious learned men" refer to normal deaths or will be killed in a war or maybe killed? Are there any other hadith that has more details?

Comment: I don't remember any text(Quran or Hadith) that interchangeably uses the term death in the context of murder or natural death rather I only remember it in specific context, based on this the hadith could be referring to natural death

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any other hadees for such matter, this hadees is all we got.

Deaths of people of knowledge can be in any way, as this hadees does not mention anything special so we will take general meaning which is both natural death or killings in any way.

**This hadees indicates that people of knowledge will die before they could have transferred their knowledge to the next generation.** People will have the book of Allah, and the ahadees and any other aasaar but not the people who have thorough understanding of these.

Allah knows best.

Answer (score 0):

Allah is saying after I gave you knowledge I wont take it away from you. That being said if a great scholar dies you would lose access to his wisdom, the narrations he tells you, the applications of narrations, etc.

There are narrations that say the death of a *عالم* scholar is 70 more harmful to the Ummah than the death of an *عابد*  servant.